# Yammer API - Avoid sending a confirmation email

Tags: rest, api, email, yammer

I have a .NET console application that add a list of users in a selected Yammer group through `[/group_memberships.json]` endpoint and it works fine.

Anyway the customer wants to avoid the sending of a confirmation email to user that has been added. In fact, after my program runs, all users receive an email like "XXX has added you to the YYY group on Yammer. Go to group".

The only way that I found to avoid this email is disable email notification in user settings.
Is there another simple way? Through Rest API is possible tell to Yammer to do not send email or, otherwise, change the user settings? I'm asking it because there're some hidden Rest API not documented in the official Yammer site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yammer doesn't have any API endpoint to achieve your objective. Your customer may consider adding a rule in exchange to block emails based on the "from" address and certain keywords in the "subject".